# Cmake error build lib

Tags: cmake, makefile, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I write simple Protobuf-C lib. While compile it to lib i Have follow error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target ArgentumTracer-native
[ 16%] Building C object CMakeFiles/ArgentumTracer-native.dir/src/sources/http_sender.c.o
/Users/rmuhamedgaliev/Projects/ArgentumTracer-native/src/sources/http_sender.c:36:33: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'in_addr_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *') to parameter of type 'struct in_addr *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    if ( inet_aton(SERVER_ADDR, &dest.sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 )
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/arpa/inet.h:83:47: note: passing argument to parameter here
int              inet_aton(const char *, struct in_addr *);
                                                         ^
1 warning generated.
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/ArgentumTracer-native.dir/src/sources/main_agent.c.o
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/ArgentumTracer-native.dir/src/sources/VMInfo.pb-c.c.o
Linking C executable ArgentumTracer-native
[ 50%] Built target ArgentumTracer-native
Scanning dependencies of target argentumtracer
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/argentumtracer.dir/src/sources/http_sender.c.o
/Users/rmuhamedgaliev/Projects/ArgentumTracer-native/src/sources/http_sender.c:36:33: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'in_addr_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *') to parameter of type 'struct in_addr *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    if ( inet_aton(SERVER_ADDR, &dest.sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 )
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/arpa/inet.h:83:47: note: passing argument to parameter here
int              inet_aton(const char *, struct in_addr *);
                                                         ^
1 warning generated.
[ 83%] Building C object CMakeFiles/argentumtracer.dir/src/sources/main_agent.c.o
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/argentumtracer.dir/src/sources/VMInfo.pb-c.c.o
Linking C shared library libargentumtracer.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_protobuf_c_message_free_unpacked", referenced from:
      _vminfo__free_unpacked in VMInfo.pb-c.c.o
  "_protobuf_c_message_get_packed_size", referenced from:
      _vminfo__get_packed_size in VMInfo.pb-c.c.o
  "_protobuf_c_message_pack", referenced from:
      _vminfo__pack in VMInfo.pb-c.c.o
  "_protobuf_c_message_pack_to_buffer", referenced from:
      _vminfo__pack_to_buffer in VMInfo.pb-c.c.o
  "_protobuf_c_message_unpack", referenced from:
      _vminfo__unpack in VMInfo.pb-c.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libargentumtracer.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/argentumtracer.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

CMakeLists.txt

```html
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(ArgentumTracer-native)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

FIND_PACKAGE(Java REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(JNI REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2})

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "src/sources/*.c" "src/sources/*.h")

add_executable(ArgentumTracer-native ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_library(argentumtracer SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(ArgentumTracer-native protobuf-c)
```

Please help me build lib. My repository placed in github [repository](https://github.com/BotAnalyser/ArgentumTracer-native) branch **develop**

Comment: You'll need to share you CMake code at a minimum. At first glance, it looks like you're not finding/linking the protobuf libraries correctly.

Comment: I placed full source code in repository.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my comment, you need to use CMake to find protobuf and add the protobuf library to your target_link_libraries. You do have the library, protobuf-c, explicitly stated in the links, but that's not really a fool-proof way to go. To be sure, you should try the following ....

```
find_package(Protobuf MODULE)
if(NOT PROTOBUF_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "-- Protobuf is required!")
endif()

target_link_libraries(ArgentumTracer-native ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

Now, you can be certain that you have your correct library. Further, if protobuf can't be found, you'll know when the find_package fails and have the chance to give CMake the true location.